# Component without a dialog won't display in Sidekick

Tags: aem

If a component is created, but a `dialog.xml` file isn't included within it, it will not show as available within the Sidekick, even if enabled in Design mode, and with a Component Group specified — why is this?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: created one component and included property componentgroup, i observed that with out creating dialog i am unable to see the component in side-kick even though i gave component group.

Answer (score 4):

If you add a cq:editConfig node to the component it will show up in the sidekick, after being enabled in the design dialog of the parsys, without having a dialog.

As reference: [http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/developing/components.html#Components and their structure](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/developing/components.html#Components%20and%20their%20structure)

Answer (score 3):

dialog boxes are meant for dynamically adding  content to the components.
if there is no dialog box in a component there is no reason for component to display in sidekick .
u can directly hard code the component like this.

```
<cq:include path="par0" resourceType="/apps/...." />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone into the design portion to allow your component?  I've often created a new component, and been unable to add it simply because I forgot to allow it in the design mode on that page.

EDIT

Good point - I do believe a dialog.xml file is required for it to show up in the sidekick.  Otherwise you have to hard code the include of your component where you need it.  I would suggest adding a dialog.xml file, even if it is only for the reason of showing it in the sidekick, so you can add it dynamically to different pages.

Comment: I think even with the component enabled in Design, it still won't be included in the Sidekick if you haven't given it a `dialog.xml` file. Not sure what the reasoning behind it is, but think it's expected behaviour alright.